# Livewire Sortable is reversing order view after drop

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire, sortablejs

I am using the Livewire Sortable plugin for my Laravel 8 project. I followed the documentation as follows:

1- Setting the CDN script link after `@livewirescript` in the

> app.blade.php

```
    @stack('modals')

        @livewireScripts
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@nextapps-be/livewire-sortablejs@0.1.1/dist/livewire-sortable.js"></script>

</body>
```

2- In the livewire component i implemented the following code:

```
<div class="text-gray-700" wire:sortable="updateTaskOrder">
        @if($data->count())
        @foreach($data as $item)
        <div class="flex items-start space-x-2" wire:sortable.item="{{ $item->id }}"
            wire:key="task-{{ $item->id }}">
            <div class="flex justify-between items-start w-full">
                <div>
                    <div class="px-4 pt-2 text-sm font-semibold" >{{$item->name}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                    <x-buttons.edit-small wire:click="openModalU({{$item->id}})" />
                    <x-buttons.delete-small wire:click="openModalD({{$item->id}})" />
                    <button wire:sortable.handle><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                            fill="currentColor">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M3 4a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zm0 4a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zm0 4a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zm0 4a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1z"
                                clip-rule="evenodd" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
        @endif
    </div>
```

3- In the Livewire model I referred to the function `updateTaskOrder()` using the following code:

```
public function updateTaskOrder($list){
        foreach($list as $item){
            Outlines::find($item['value'])->update(['sort' => $item['order']]);
        }
    }
```

The result is :

1. `<div>` is draggable
2. updates to database are working correctly

> The issue:

When dragged `<div>` is dropped in new position it is reverting to its old position after a couple of seconds, yet not triggering `updateTaskOrder()` function.

Could you please help me understand the behavior of the view and what can be done to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

After 3 days it seems it was a simple trick. The solution was to render data after update directly, this will prevent.

in the `updateTaskOrder()` you will have the following:

```
public function updateTaskOrder($list){
    foreach($list as $item){
        Outlines::find($item['value'])->update(['sort' => $item['order']]);
    }
    $this->data = Outlines::where('course_id','=',$this->courseId)->orderBy('sort')->get(); 
    
    $this->emitSelf('refreshComponent');
}
```

And in the `render()` function will be as such:

```
public function render()
{
    $data =  $this->data;
    return view('livewire.profiles-components.course-profile.outline-profile',compact('data'));
}
```

Thank you for everyone that viewed my post.

Comment: Can you post the code change you made so it helps others in the future

Comment: sure, thank you.